# How to run tests from gradle task in heroku before creating slug?

Tags: spring, docker, jenkins, heroku, build.gradle

I am trying to automate some tasks. Currently my jenkins job performs heroku buildpacks and creates slug to be deployed.

But heroku/gradle buildpack, won't run unit tests & and other tests which can be configured locally with the help of libraries and docker.

I want to either create my custom buildpack which would run something like:
./gradlew taskName(~defined in build.gradle)

Or is there a way I can customize this instead of running | ./gradlew build -x check - which I believe is default in heroku/gradle buildpack and can be replaced by

./gradlew build -x check && ./gradlew taskName

Is this achievable? Any help is appreciated.

Thank you!